# Is there a way to convince JetBrains PyCharm to autocomplete field names when using annotated dataclasses?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I currently have a program that is translating a protocol with many different message types to Python, and have used annotated dataclasses to represent the messages.  For example:

```py
@dataclass()
class TriggerEvent:
    sequence_num: int = 0
    num_sub_messages: int = 0
    carryover: dict[bytes, Ledger] = field(default_factory=lambda: {}) # Note Ledger is another dataclass defined in a similar way
    qrs: list[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    trs: list[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    tss: list[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    last_tss: list[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: []) 
    observed: bool = False
    sub_messages: list[SubTriggerEvents] = field(default_factory=lambda: []) # Note SubTriggerEvents is another dataclass defined in a similar way
```

This is a relatively simple example, some of these message types have dozens of fields.

In the actual code, the "main loop" ends up looking something like this:

```py
next_event = get_next_event()
if type(next_event) is TriggerEvent:
   ....
```

It would be lovely if I could get JetBrains' code completion to automatically list fields when I hit `.` on a variable constrained to a type like `next_event.` within the 'if' statement above, or if a method has a type hint in the signature.

Is there any ways to convince the PyCharm to do this?

Comment: I don't use pycharm myself, but have you tried using pattern matching instead of the old if(type()) style type checking? So: `match get_next_event(): case TriggerEvent:`

Comment: @somethingsomething Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you say: *" a variable constrained to a type like `event_type`"* there is no variable in your code of type `event_type` so readers have no way of knowing what you mean.  Then you have 2 source fences but there's never a place where code completion could be activated in the code, we're also left to fill in that blank. I also think that throwing in `get_next_event()` complicates things because there you'd need to type hint the return and the receiving variable - that alone should be enough for code completion to work.

Comment: Your `TriggerEvent` also has too many fields, you should post it narrowed down to a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bad_coder Some variable names got mangled in edits, `event_type` should be `next_event` and has been fixed.  I also disagree this isn't a fairly minimal example.  I could reduce it down a couple more fields but I don't think that increases clarity.

Comment: @Chuu it hurts my eyes looking at those 9 attributes, 2 are enough. It's also a long term problem, if the example isn't minimal today every future reader will have to look at more text than is necessary.